# box-shadow перекрывается ниже стоящим блоком

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать чтобы тень верхнего блока нависала над вторым? Думал, что z-index поможет, но увы.

```html
<div style="pozition: relative;z-index: 2;height: 30px; width: 30px; border: solid 1px black;box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;"></div>
<div style="pozition: relative;background-color: red;z-index: 1;height: 30px; width: 30px; border: solid 1px black;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас ошибка `pozition` - необходимо `position`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {  
  z-index: 1;  
  background-color: #fff;  
  box-shadow: 0 20px 14px -14px #777;  
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {  
  background-color: red;    
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```